# How to deal with a date stored as a string in an int field in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got a table in Teradata that stores a date in an 8 character INT field in the following form "YYYYMMDD", so for today it would store "20180308". If I try to CAST it as a date like this:

`CAST(date_field AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

It transforms the date to some future date in the year 3450 or something.

I think it's an error that this data isn't either stored as a date object. Is there anyway to overcome this glitch? I don't have access to change this unfortunately.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an 8 *character* integer, it's an 8 *digit* integer.

Teradata stores dates using

```
(year - 1900) * 10000
+ (month * 100)
+ day
```

This results in `1180308` for today and `20180308` will return `3918-03-08`

To cast it to a date you need to use

```
cast(intdate-19000000 as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

select cast('20180308' as date format 'yyyymmdd')  ;

Comment: Yeah, so this gives me a date somehwere in the year 3980 or something.

Comment: select cast((cast(20180308 as char(8))) as date format 'yyyymmdd')  ;